# View in fragment is null sometimes

Tags: android

I have a fragment that starts the camera and shows what the camera sees in a preview. I saw on Firebase that I got the error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.Display.getRotation()' on a null object reference
       at com.name.app.maincontroller.CameraActivityFragment.startCamera$lambda-1(CameraFragment.kt:137)
       at com.name.app.maincontroller.CameraActivityFragment.$r8$lambda$Baw0zungVg9sQysXA5zq_tOQHPI()
       at com.name.app.maincontroller.CameraActivityFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(:4)
```

The error message is quite clear, the function that crashes looks like:

```
private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
        cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()
        // Set up the view finder use case to display camera preview
        preview = Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(cameraPreview.display.rotation)  // <- This crashes
            .build()
        try {
            bindVideoCapture()
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e("TestCameraPytorch", "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(cameraPreview.surfaceProvider)
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
}
```

I have followed some tutorials to start the camera etc, the code is probably not perfect.

`cameraPreview` is set here:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    cameraCaptureButton = view.findViewById(R.id.camera_capture_button)
    cameraPreview = view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview)
    setRecordVideoListener()
}
```

What can make the view null?

Another thing, in `startCamera`, `val cameraProvider` is local, but a listener is assigned to it. Is that really good? Feels like `cameraProvider` should have a longer life time.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating all of the view dependent references while you know they are accessible, because you are creating them in a callback there is no guarantee the fragment is in an acceptable lifecycle state to provide you those references. ie `cameraPreview` If the Camera is bound by the fragments lifecycle it should be stable when it uses those view dependent references. ie `preview`

```
private fun startCamera() {
    preview = Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(cameraPreview.display.rotation)
            .build()
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(cameraPreview.surfaceProvider)
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
    Futures.addCallback(
       cameraProviderFuture, 
       new FutureCallback<ProcessCameraProvider>() {
              fun onSuccess(provider: ProcessCameraProvider) {
                  provider.unbindAll()
                  try {
                     bindVideoCapture()
                  } catch (exc: Exception) {
                     Log.e("TestCameraPytorch", "Use case binding failed", exc)
                  }
              }
              fun onFailure(t : Throwable) {
                  reportError(t)
              }
      },
      ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I tried that but then it started to crash all the time since `cameraPreview.display` was null all the time. How can that come?

Comment: If I change to `cameraPreview.rotation.toInt()` it works on my phone.

Comment: The version in my question works on my phone, but on a friend's phone it crashes.

Comment: Maybe one should not even use display, followed some example from Pytorch I think.